# Não reconhecendo arquivo js quando está em 2 pastas

Tags: javascript

Bom o meu html nao ta reconhecendo o arquivo js quando eu coloco em 2 pastas por exemplo, quando eu coloco

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Não funciona mesmo o arquivo estando la, depois eu movi o arquivo somente para js/scripts.js e funcionou normalmente, alguem pode me dizer o que está causando isso.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU1m8.png

PS: Ali ta asssets, com 3 "S", mas coloquei errado só na hora de tirar print mesmo.

Comment: "PS: Ali ta asssets, com 3 "S", mas coloquei errado só na hora de tirar print mesmo."

Comment: Coloque "<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>" antes do fechamento do body, e não fora dele.

Comment: Continua no desmo jeito, não funcionando...

Comment: Acho que você não leu o tópico, é problema na hora de chamar ele, quando coloco em js/scripts.js ou no diretorio direto do site funciona perfeitamente, agora se eu coloco em 2 pastas, assets/js/scripts.js não funciona.

Comment: Só acho melhor ler a pergunta bem antes de responder, explicar mais que isso não tem como, mas obrigado por responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque a tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>` antes do fechamento do body `</body>` ao invés de fora dele antes do `</html>`.

Exemplificando:

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
        hideElement...
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**OBS:** Não é mais necessário especificar o `type` nas tags `LINK` e `SCRIPT` visto que está utilizando HTML5.

Ficando:

```
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Documentação: [**Scripting - W3  Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)

**OBS:**
Verifique também o seu `.htaccess`. Ele pode estar bloqueando o acesso aos diretórios.

Comment: Continua no desmo jeito, não funcionando...

Comment: Acho que você não leu o tópico, é problema na hora de chamar ele, quando coloco em js/scripts.js ou no diretorio direto do site funciona perfeitamente, agora se eu coloco em 2 pastas, assets/js/scripts.js não funciona.

Comment: Sim, várias vezes, até mudei o nome da pasta assets, mas continua não funcionando :/

Comment: Olha, primeiro em 2 pastas aa/js http://prntscr.com/5yr7n5 resultado http://prntscr.com/5yr7tx depois em 1 pasta só, js/  http://prntscr.com/5yr83j resultado http://prntscr.com/5yr7z0

Comment: O código está correto, o caminho está correto. Aquele .htaccess está bloqueando algum diretório?

Comment: Lol, era o .htaccess, coloquei deny from all, mas antes eu havia tirado e o erro persistia, agora retirei e está funcionando noralmente, muito obrigado.